# SQL Server 2012 CHECK MY SQL QUERY BEFORE I UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, ssms, sql-update

I have this update query but I do not want to run before I check what changes it will make.

```
UPDATE tblControls_ContractSetpointProfile
SET CoolingOccupied = 76
FROM tblMEP_Sites
JOIN tblControls_ContractSetpoint ON tblControls_ContractSetpointProfile.ID = ContractSetpointID
WHERE ProjectID in (28, 47)
```

I though I just need to replace `UPDATE WITH SELECT` but that did not work. The answer to this question does not work, please do not change anything as I see `SET CoolingOccupied = 76` is missing in the solution. I am not a database programmer but I have to do this because the person who is supposed to do this is absent. Thank you for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

To see what will be modified, run this query:

```
SELECT CoolingOccupied
FROM tblMEP_Sites
JOIN tblControls_ContractSetpoint ON tblControls_ContractSetpointProfile.ID = ContractSetpointID
WHERE ProjectID in (28, 47)
```

The rows returned by this will be the rows that will be updated by your query.

When doing the update, you could also perform it within a transaction, that way you can verify the rows that it updates before deciding to commit or rollback if it isn't what you expect.